# Nested conditional statements for flowplayer

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't the below mentioned code work?

```
<script>
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.8.swf", {
    onLoad: function() { 
        this.setVolume(100); 
    },
    clip: {   
        autoBuffering: true,  
    },
var screenwidth = screen.width;
var screenheight = screen.height;
if (screenwidth / screenheight < 1.34) {
    <!--[if IE]>
         <plugins: {
     controls: null
     }/>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
         <plugins: {
     controls: true
     }/>
    <!--<![endif]-->
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you add added flowplayer-3.2.8.swf in your project file

Comment: There is no source of video to play for flow player

Comment: Did you add the script which is responsible for adding the plugin? Also do not use work like `some 1` to represent `someone`. Sometimes it also make you lusers. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, from Australia 1. What's it like seven dimensions over?

Answer (score 0):

```
 flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.8.swf", {

        onLoad: function() { 
            this.setVolume(100); 
        },
        clip: {   
            autoBuffering: true,
    url: video_path  
        },

here video_path is the path of your video
```

Comment: Hi silentboy. I would have used "word" instead of "work" and "loser" instead of "lusers". I would have also changed your grammar to "Sometimes it also makes you a loser". Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
 <?php
   echo '<a href="'.{VIDEO PATH HERE}.'" style="display:block;width:631px;height:361px" id="player">  </a>';
   echo '<script>
          flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {  
             \'plugins\': {
             \'sharing\': {
             \'url\': \'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.sharing-3.2.10.swf\',

             \'buttons\': {
             \'overColor\': \'#ff0000\'
         },
         \'email\': {
             \'subject\': \'A cool video\'
         },
         \'embed\': {
             \'fallbackUrls\': [ \'Extremists.mov\' ]
         },

         \'facebook\': {
             \'shareWindow\': \'_popup\'
         },

         \'twitter\': true
         },
         \'dock\': {
             \'right\': 15,
             \'horizontal\': false,
             \'width\': \'10%\',
             \'autoHide\': false
         }
      },
      clip:  {
         autoPlay: false,
         autoBuffering: true
      }
   });
  </script>';
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi Soumya Roy. Thanks for your php code, however it still doesnt address what I believe is the core of my problem - the nested conditional IE statements inside a flowplayer call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, Dolours. I have added flowplayer in my project file but didnt include it here as I thought it was assumed. This is what appears in my header;

```
<script src="http://www.dyslexiaservices.com.au/new/flowplayer-3.2.8.min.js"></script>
```

If you remove everything below "clip", the code works fine with or without a video path (I have tried both). The problem appears to be with the conditional IE statements.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, nnnnnn. The seven dimensional rift appears to have a gravitational effect, reversing the flow of water down the sink. Possibly as a compensatory measure, large quantities of beer are consumed in response.